How do I fill out a PDF form containing text and dropdown fields using Python's pypdf module?
Though I am not technically new to Python, I have not used it in five years, so I may as well call myself a novice. I picked it back up because I need to bulk fill PDF forms. I am working in a contained environment, therefore I have to work with packages and versions that I already have. I have Python 3.11.7, pypdf 4.3.1. I do not have fillpdf or PyMuPDF and cannot import them. I am following an example from pypdf documentation here: https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/forms.html. However, the fields are not being populated for some reason. I have discovered by accidentally running a previous command writer.append_pages_from_reader(reader) before writer.append(reader) that this works though all my pages are duplicated (my three page doc turned into six pages but the fields are populated.) Running either of those lines without the other resuts in an unpopulated form.
from pypdf import PdfReader, PdfWriter

reader = PdfReader("form.pdf")
writer = PdfWriter()

page = reader.pages[0]
fields = reader.get_fields()

# Line directly below is the one that was added by accident
writer.append_pages_from_reader(reader)
writer.append(reader)

writer.update_page_form_field_values(
    writer.pages[0],
    {"fieldname": "some filled in text"},
    auto_regenerate=False)

with open("filled-out.pdf", "wb") as output_stream:
    writer.write(output_stream)


I could do this to fill out the form and then go back and delete the extra pages programmatically like this: How to delete pages from pdf file using Python?. I would however prefer a cleaner solution.
My other issue is, there are a couple of drop-down fields. pypdf documentation does not provide any code examples for this fairly common scenario. I was looking at the following question: PyPDF2 change field value without dictionary where the author answers his own question. The solution is to edit the dropdown object to be plain text obj.update({NameObject('/FT'): NameObject('/Tx')}). What would my obj be? I do not want to change all dropdowns to text, only the ones on the first page (objects 4 and 5.) I tried the code below also following this post: Change fields in pdf using pypdf?, no error but but no change either.
import pypdf
from pypdf import generic as pypdf_generic

field_object = page.get('/Annots').get_object()[5].get_object()
field_object.update({pypdf_generic.NameObject('/FT'): pypdf_generic.NameObject('/Tx')})


Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Have you tried using writer = PdfWriter(clone_from="form.pdf") directly instead of using an additional reader? For dropdown fields: Determine the possible values using writer.get_fields()["fieldname"]. Then just use update_page_form_field_values as usual with your desired target value.

Thank you @epR8GaYuh. I will try implementing some of your suggestions and keep you posted. If you have a working script and want to share it as an answer, I will mark it as a solution if it works for me.

@epR8GaYuh, your second suggestion worked. I was able to determine the possible values using writer.get_fields()["fieldname"] then use update_page_form_field_values. However your first suggestion gave me a document with blank fields. The only thing that seems to fill out the form (while duplicating the document pages, i.e. instead of pages 1, 2, 3 I have pages 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3) is running writer.append_pages_from_reader(reader) followed by writer.append(reader).

I gave this a few days and since my question did not receive much traction and I had to come up with a solution, I would like to share it. To make a long story short, I was only able to fill out form fields when using the code in the original question, the code that duplicated my form. I then went back and deleted the extra pages. I was able to select dropdown fields epR8GaYuh's suggestion (first comment to my post.) My form looks almost perfect though the text is top justified while I would prefer it to be bottom justified.
from pypdf import PdfReader, PdfWriter

reader = PdfReader("form.pdf")
writer = PdfWriter()
output = PdfWriter()

page = reader.pages[0]
fields = reader.get_fields()

# Line directly below is the one that was added by accident
writer.append_pages_from_reader(reader)
writer.append(reader)

# Fill out the form
writer.update_page_form_field_values(
    writer.pages[0],
    {"text_field_name" : "some filled in text",
     "dropdown_field_name" : "dropdown option"},
    auto_regenerate=False)

# Delete duplicated pages
pages_to_keep = [0, 1, 2]

for i in pages_to_keep:
    p = writer.pages[i]
    output.add_page(p)

# Save the form
with open("filled-out.pdf", "wb") as output_stream:
    output.write(output_stream)

This not a clean solution I was hoping for but it does the job. If anyone has a suggestion on how to bottom justify the filled out text values or not have to create and then delete duplicate pages, I would very much appreciate your comments and/or suggestions.
